In AnyLogic, how can I create a flow of materials such that materials only flow to the next area if there is space for them?
In AnyLogic, ow can I create a flow of materials such that materials only flow to the next area if there is space for them? (Pull system)
A large delivery of goods is unloaded to an unloading area. I then want to move some of the goods to a staging area with a limited capacity.
Goods are labeled at the staging area and then moved to another area which also has limited space.
I want transporters (people or AMRs) to move the goods, but only when the next area has space for them.
I tried using logic with queues with limited capacity, but this did not seem to stop good being moved through the system.

You could have the total available space as a resource on a resource pool. This way, each good could have to seize (occupy) a free space before entering the move blocks. And when they free the space they release the resource (space)

Thank you, I will investigate this method.
